# Tip Calculator results in NaN

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner, working on a beginner problem but need some help

I am trying to write my own tip calculator app but I result in NaN.

I am sure it is an easy fix but I don't see what the problem is yet. My code is below. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong that results in my finalCost resulting in NaN instead of billAmount + tipTotal?

```js
var billAmount = prompt('What is your total bill?');

var tipAmount = prompt('How much do you want to tip');

console.log(billAmount);

var tip = tipAmount / 100;

var tipTotal = tip * billAmount;

function finalCost(billAmount, tipTotal) {
  return billAmount + tipTotal;
};

console.log("The tip is " + tipTotal);
console.log("The total bill is " + finalCost());
```

Comment: You need to pass the bill amount and tiptotal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another catch; setting `float` values directly from a `prompt()` doesn't ensure `float` values (treated as `string` by default), so wrap your `prompt()` functions in a `parseFloat()` function:

```js
var billAmount = parseFloat(prompt('What is your total bill?'));
var tipAmount = parseFloat(prompt('How much do you want to tip'));

if(isNaN(billAmount) || isNaN(tipAmount)){
     alert("Bill amount or Tip is Invalid");
} else {
    console.log("This bill is " + billAmount);

    var tip = tipAmount / 100;
    var tipTotal = tip * billAmount;

    console.log("The tip is " + tipTotal);
    console.log("The total bill is " + finalCost(billAmount, tipTotal));
}

function finalCost(billAmount, tipTotal) {
  return billAmount + tipTotal;
};
```

This should validate that `billAmount` and `tipAmount` values are `float`s, and prevent further execution if they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

So close! You just missed passing the values into your final calculation method.

```js
var billAmount = prompt('What is your total bill?');

var tipAmount = prompt('How much do you want to tip');

console.log(billAmount);

var tip = tipAmount/100;

var tipTotal = tip*billAmount;

function finalCost(billAmount, tipTotal) {
 return billAmount + tipTotal;
};

console.log("The tip is " + tipTotal);
console.log("The total bill is " + finalCost(billAmount, tipTotal));
```

You could also remove the parameters and just use the "global" values in calculating

```js
var billAmount = prompt('What is your total bill?');

var tipAmount = prompt('How much do you want to tip');

console.log(billAmount);

var tip = tipAmount/100;

var tipTotal = tip*billAmount;

function finalCost() {
 return billAmount + tipTotal;
};

console.log("The tip is " + tipTotal);
console.log("The total bill is " + finalCost());
```

Comment: I get something funny when I enter `15` and `5`; instead of `20` (or `15.75`, 5% vs $5) I get `150.75`. Looks like there's some string concatenation going on there :P

Comment: That is what I am noticing. Do you see where I am making the mistake?

Comment: @YankeeJohn Yes, because the billAmount is user input it is put in as a String. Simply wrap billAmount with `Number(billAmount)` and you should get the number. Long run... maybe some validation that it is a number since that isn't a guarantee or safe.